# How to print hard copy from python application

Tags: python, kivy

I have an application developed with kivy python. I have a screen that allows the user to print data generated on that screen and I have a print button. How do I make the print button print the entire data on that screen. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import os 

import temp file

File = tempfile.mktemp(“.txt”)

Open(file, “w”).write(text.get(1.0,END))

os.startfile(file, “print”)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.